# How do I write a UML state diagram?

Tags: uml

How do you draw a UML State Diagram that models the high level state transition for a work schedule? I have tried looking at YouTube videos, but I don't understand the steps of writing a state diagram.

Comment: SO is not a learning platform. Make an effort and when you got stuck come back with that one issue. Good luck.

Comment: I have made an effort, i have looked on youtube but i dont understand the information, do you know where i can study?

Comment: look here: http://www.uml-diagrams.org/state-machine-diagrams.html

Comment: i have done my version do you have a email address i can sent to?

Comment: You may include your diagram in your question, so that you may get answers from several people.

Comment: Put the image on a public server and post the link. Someone here can take care to add it to your question.